# Use Ceph as redundant storage for failover FTP service?

Tags: storage, failover, ceph

I need to setup a redundant FTP storage service that can survive one server-crash.

I have two servers *SrvA* and *SrvB* that shares a virtual IP *IpVirt* (an IP that will usually point to *SrvA* but that will point to *SrvB* if *SrvA* were to have a problem).
Both servers (Debian) will have a FTP daemon and FTP users configured.

At this point the FTP daemon can always be reached using *IpVirt*: failover FTP service = OK

For the actual storage part I see the following options:

- `rsync` the FTP *data* directory between *SrvA* and *SrvB*
- Use a replicated file system whose nodes are *SrvA* and *SrvB*: The replicated FS infrastructure would do the synchronization job for me.

I am considering the second option: and I wonder if Ceph (which I would like to try) could do the job?

Can I make *SrvA* and *SrvB* the two nodes of a Ceph infrastructure where datas are stored on both *SrvA* and *SrvB*.
But also make that Ceph infrastructure still be accessible by any Ceph client (*SrvA*, *SrvB* or any other) when at least one of *SrvA* or *SrvB* is up? A Ceph "master" failover system (client would be using that same *IpVirt* IP).

In this scenario, the FTP *data* directory would be a mountpoint for a Ceph "volume".

Note: I plan to use theses two servers for other storage oriented services (SMB, WebDAV, storage-oriented web applications...). Theses services' *data* directory would then be other mountpoints to other Ceph "volumes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ceph needs quite many nodes to aggregate reasonable performance.

http://ceph.com/planet/zero-to-hero-guide-for-ceph-cluster-planning/

If you only have two DRBD is your best friend.

http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/ch07.html